# How to change Textinputlayout text color when is not active

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I am working on the signup page of my android app and am using textinputlayout. When the edittext is click on the color of the line and hint changes but if it not active the color of the hint is black. I want to change the color of the hint from black to white when not active.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <EditText
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
    android:id="@+id/firstNameEditText"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


   <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>

</style>


<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#252c52</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorBlack">#000</color>
<color name="colorWhite">#FFF</color>
<color name="colorBackground">#e9ecf1</color>
<color name="background">#3F51B5</color>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try adding `android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"` to your `TextInputLayout`

Comment: @aytek I have add it but it is not working for me

Comment: Can you share the value for @color/colorWhite ?

Comment: @aytek I have updated my question with reference to your question. thanks